# Woocommerce sale price schedule using UTC instead of local timezone

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’ve found that Woocommerce is using UTC time for schedule date price end instead of the local time, even if :

- The date in WordPress is set up to Europe/Paris
- The server time is Europe/Paris

**What I've done :**

- On a staging site, I've enable only Woocommerce + Storefront theme.
- I tested it with 2 different hosting companies
- Verify that php.ini have the correct timezone
- Verify server time with `date` command in the shell

**What's the result :**

Woocommerce is always using UTC time to display Sale date end (instead of local timezone), no matter what is your settings. See below the Woocommerce system report :

```
### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 7.4.32
PHP Post Max Size: 512 Mo
PHP Time Limit: 3600
PHP Max Input Vars: 250000
cURL Version: 7.71.0
OpenSSL/1.1.1p

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.5.5-10.3.36-MariaDB
Max Upload Size: 512 Mo
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔
```

I've found 2 interresting posts talk about it :

- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/26347
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/20680

I don't know what I can do more.